# Create file from output on single line

Tags: linux, shell

I am currently stuck on a question which asks:

> A ‘file’ in the /proc directory contains information about the processor. Use commands to search this file for information about the processor cache, and save the output in a file cache.txt

I have managed to get to the output part but cannot get the output to save to a file. Here is my sample code:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'cache'
```

This display the desired output on the terminal

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'cache' > cache.txt
```

This is my modified command to save the output to a file called cache.txt but it says the file is not there. My only thoughts could be as I am running the command from inside /proc, do I need to specify the file path for the file cache.txt I want to create?

Sample code:

```sh
/proc $ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i cache > cache.txt
bash: cache.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can't create new files in /proc, no.

Comment: Please don't use images and instead paste what you actually did in the question, much clearer and some don't look at images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it in `/proc` directory which is a virtual filesystem,
you cannot create new files in it. You have to save output `cache.txt`
in a different directory. For example, to save it in your home
directory type `cd` with no arguments and then do:

```
grep -i cache /proc/cpuinfo > cache.txt
```

cache.txt will look like that:

```
$ cat cache.txt
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
cache size      : 8192 KB
cache_alignment : 64
```

Comment: That's what happens when an image is used and not looked at :)

Comment: Awesome thank you!

Does it matter the order of the command? 

grep -i cache /proc/cpuinfo > cache.txt 

seems to do the same as:

cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'cache' > cache.txt

but you dont need the pipe operator in yours

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @cEz: sorry, order of what commands? Can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part, the comment must have been edited. Both commands will lead to the same effect but you don't have to use `cat` - version without `cat` is shorter and better performance-wise because you don't spawn an external process.

Comment: @cEz: it looks like you edited your comment too and I thought you're asking me xD

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, I was editing immediately. A combination of using mobile + browser + this site meant that it didn't like what I was typing. We can clean up the irrelevant comments